# Id of foreign key set as 0

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a DB-First Entity Framework setup with a Customer with a nullable foreign key to table Address.
The Customer model is defined this way:

```
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? AddressId { get; set; } // same name as foreign key field on db

    [DataMember]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a customer from db with an associated address:

```
Customer getCustomerById(int id) {
    return _db.Customers.Include("Address").SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

I get the `Customer` with the relevant `Address` set and filled with the correct field, but `customer.AddressId` and `customer.Address.Id` are set to `0`, while in the db the record is something like:

```
Id  | AddressId
----------------
12  |      3288
```

Why is that so? I couldn't find anything about this in the net, only a warning about Eager Loading not working with `Include`s, but in Customer there are other (non nullable) fields included the same way that are loaded with a correct Id.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Your link seems to be bad: did you point out specific resources that would need to be reposted or can I just google "how to log SQL" and call it a day? :)

Comment: Yes. Otherwise here is another try. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: What does the `Address` class look like? Is it mapped properly?

Comment: It seems so. The id field is marked as key and is capitalized as per SQL Server standard:

 `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
 public class Address
 {
  [DataMember]
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; } ...
        }`. Also all `Address` fields (aside from the id itself) are correctly loaded from the DB.